# Get ID of "root-page"

Tags: id

I have an url that looks like this
http://apploadny.appload.nu/tjanster/webbutveckling/
I want to get the ID of the page "tjanster", how can i do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think what you need is:

```
<?php 
$post_id = $post->ID; //or somehow get the current post ID.
$ancestors = get_post_ancestors($post_id)  
//$ancestors is an array of post IDs starting with the current post going up the root
//'Pop' the root ancestor out or returns the current ID if the post has no ancestors.
$root_id = (!empty($ancestors) ? array_pop($ancestors): $post_id);
```

For more info check: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_ancestors

Comment: Hope you don't mind the edits :D

Comment: Thank you very much! I tried alexleonard's solution first, and it worked, but then i ran into the issue when im at "subpages" i still want to display the "grandparents" menu. It works great now with the edit :) Thank You!

Comment: Please **accept** this answer (using the checkmark beneath the question up/down voting buttons), if it resolves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think a better solution than @alexleonard 's is to use the `parent_id` parameter of the post object.

```
$parent = ( $post_obj->parent_id != 0 ) ? $post_obj->parent_id : false;
```

Haven't tested that, so make sure you check for spelling mistakes and such.

Comment: alexleonard's method will get the top-level parent (parent of parent of parent, etc.), which seems to be what Anton wants.

Comment: @AdamBackstrom I'm not sure that that's the case...I think the question could be read either way (having reread it, I can see your point though)